# Object referencing confusion

Tags: java, object, reference

I am getting a `NullPointerException on the MainClass.ob1.noOfVerts` variable in the following code:

---

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class drawr extends JPanel{

    public void paintComponent(Graphics g){

        super.paintComponent(g);
        g.setColor(Color.decode("#ffc000"));
        g.drawLine(0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight());
        for(int cnt=0; cnt/displayObject.dim*2<=**MainClass.ob1.noOfVerts**; cnt+=displayObject.dim*2){
            g.drawLine(MainClass.ob1.coords[cnt], MainClass.ob1.coords[cnt+1], MainClass.ob1.coords[cnt+2], MainClass.ob1.coords[cnt+3]);
        }
    }
```

The object is instantiated here:

```
import java.awt.Color;
import javax.swing.*;

public class MainClass{

    public static final int windowWidth = 1280;
    public static final int windowHeight = 640;
    public static boolean crash = false;

    public static displayObject **ob1**, ob2, ob3;

    public static void main(String[] args)
        throws InterruptedException {

        String colorString="#ff0000";
        int ob1verts[]={10,10,50,50,30,80};
        **displayObject ob1=new displayObject("#ff0000", ob1verts);**
        int ob2verts[]={30,50,70,90,130,180,75,30};
        displayObject ob2=new displayObject("#00ff00", ob2verts);
        int ob3verts[]={10,10,70,50,70,80,110,130,30,30};
        displayObject ob3=new displayObject("#0000ff", ob3verts);
```

with this constructor:

```
  public class displayObject {

        //  Each object is defined by a color, number of vertices, and dim (2,3,4) coordinate vertex locations
        //  Use dim to verify that the right number of vertices were sent

            public static int dim=2;

            public String color;
            **public int noOfVerts**;
            public int coords [];

            public displayObject (String col, int verts[]){

                if (verts.length%dim != 0){
                    System.out.printf ("Crap in!");
                    return;
                }
                this.coords=new int[verts.length+2];
                color=col;
                **noOfVerts=verts.length/dim;**
                for (int cnt=0; cnt<verts.length; cnt++){
                    coords[cnt]=verts[cnt];
                }
                coords[verts.length]=verts[0];  //make last vertex equal first to close the shape
                coords[verts.length+1]=verts[1];
            }

    }
```

I've created a static variable that I would think would refer to a specific memory space for the object with an appropriate pointer.  Why is the object reference a Null Pointer?

Answer (score 1):

> The object is instantiated here:
>
> ```
> public static displayObject **ob1**, ob2, ob3;
> ```

No, that's not *instantiating* anything. It's *declaring* a variable, but it's just got its default value of `null`. At some point you need to assign a non-null value to it, e.g.

```
ob1 = new displayObject(...);
```

Now you have *this* line:

```
displayObject ob1=new displayObject("#ff0000", ob1verts);
```

... but that's not the same thing. That's declaring an entirely separate local variable, and giving *that* a value. It happens to have the same name (`ob1`) but it's a different variable. You possibly just need to change it to not be a local variable declaration:

```
ob1 = new displayObject("#ff0000", ob1verts);
```

... and ditto the other variables.

(As an aside, I'd strongly recommend avoiding non-private fields, and also starting to follow Java naming conventions.)

Comment: Whoa!  So the object type (in this case displayObject) on the left side of the declaration makes the difference in creating a new object or not.  And the new declaration creates a private (local) field?  Does declaring the variable 'static' have a function in this case outside of an object class?

Comment: @user2671186: No, not in creating a new object - in declaring a local variable or not. And private and local aren't the same thing - it's *really* important to be precise with terminology. Not sure what you mean about declaring a static field "outside of an object class", but a static field and a regular (instance) field are very different, yes.

Comment: Very helpful, thanks.  Any suggestions for places to learn or read about these things?  I don't want to do 'Hello World' type lessons, but it would be nice to have a better understanding of subjects like this.

Comment: @user2671186: Why don't you want to do "Hello World" type lessons? They're precisely designed to help you learn the basics like this.